# Azure Search SDK 11 Wildcards

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to search with the .NET SDK V11 to find all names that start with JOHN. Fuzzy search works find, John~, as well as Contains, *John*. But if I pass John*. Nothing comes back. I've tried '?' instead. Same result.

```
var options = new SearchOptions
{
 QueryType = SearchQueryType.Full,
 IncludeTotalCount = true,
 Skip = criteria.Page * criteria.PageSize,
 Size = criteria.PageSize,
};


var searchResults = await client.SearchAsync<Result>("FirstName:JOHN*", options);
```

After looking at tons of documentation on the MS site, I'm not sure what else to try. It says it should work, as well as 'Jo*n', which doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with SearchQueryType.Full you are using lucene syntax where a tilde `~` is for fuzzy search, not an asterisk `*`. In simple mode, the asterisk is for starts/ends with (not sure about middle wildcards). You can use asterisk if you do regex style, ie `John.*`. I could be wrong on all this, but worth a shot

Comment: Hmm, This is the quote from the MS site : "Full Lucene syntax supports prefix, infix, and suffix matching. However, if all you need is prefix matching, you can use the simple syntax (prefix matching is supported in both)."


 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax)

Comment: Wow, your right... which stinks because I can't mix and match Fuzzy in with the starts with on a different field...

Comment: Could you mix in Regex? Starts-with in regex is something like `^ABC.*` which means starts with "ABC" (you might not even need the `^` anchor)

Comment: 1. Is `FirstName` field defined as searchable in  your index? 2. What analyzer are you using? 3. Have you tried to specify `SearchFields` property instead of using `:` syntax?

Comment: @gleb Yes. I can search it pretty much every other way other than starts with or something like JO*N. I havent tried putting search fields in there, as it doesn't seem like I should need that since its working otherwise.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 it seems like FirstName:/JOHN.*/ is working to an extent. The issue is its looking at all fields, even though I'm specifying First Name.

Comment: I know nothing of this framework. Just did a quick search yesterday based on the enum name, thinking perhaps you were using the wrong option /shrug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to go with this solution below. Not sure why, it seems to contradict the MS documentation.

```
Filter = "search.ismatch('/John.*/,','FirstName','full','all')"
```

Works great though...